# How can I save time to calculate distance between 2097151 points in python?

Tags: python

The data I'm using is the position data of the galaxy in specific size shell. Because I want to know the amount of each distance. I calculated the distance between 2 points in xyz coordinate. After this process I'm planning to see the number(amount of each distance) and distance(between two galaxy) relation.

My code was like this

```
d = []
for i in tqdm(range(len(z)-1)):
    x1, y1, z1 = x[i], y[i], z[i]
    for j in range(len(x)):
        if j > i:
            x2, y2, z2 = x[j], y[j], z[j]
            dis = np.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2 + (z1-z2)**2)
            d = np.append(d, dis)
```

Since the shape of the data is (2097152,) the code takes too much time to get results.
So, is any efficient way to calculate this code faster?

Comment: This algorithm is clearly not efficient since it requires `2_097_152² = 4_398_046_511_104` iterations which is clearly not reasonable. Not to mention `np.append` has a quadratic execution due to new temporary arrays being created every time. You need to use a data structure like quad trees or a **ball trees**. Hopefully, [Scipy provide such a data structure](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html). Note there are several posts on Stack Overflow about this. This should take less than few seconds instead of several days.